# Javascript pass arugments to mouseover function?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm trying to set up distinct listeners for a list of objects:

```
for(i=0;i<numInputs;i++) {
    var inPort = inputPorts.get(i);
    var portName = inPort.getProperty("name");
    inPort.shape.attr({ cursor: 'pointer' }).mouseover(function(e) { mouseOverInfo.text("PORT:: "+portName); }); 
}
```

What's happening right now is that every port object is only getting the very last element's name as its own. So when I mouse over, I get returned only the last object's name.

How to do this properly?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use self-invoking function like this to avoid closure problem in loop:

```
for(i=0;i<numInputs;i++) {
  (function(i){
    var inPort = inputPorts.get(i);
    var portName = inPort.getProperty("name");
    inPort.shape.attr({ cursor: 'pointer' }).mouseover(function(e) { mouseOverInfo.text("PORT:: "+portName); }); 
  })(i)
}
```